# I used an ob_start() and clean for output buffering and now nothing will be printed to screen

Tags: php, html, sql, ob-start

I created a script as part of an online eCommerce site that using sessions, takes a product ID assigned to a button, adds that to an array, then using a var_dump, uses that ID in another script to output contents of an sql database. This is used as a basket method, as I am not very good at javascript. A problem I got was that although initially the code worked, It was also outputting the contents of the array to screen, which I did not want. So I used an output buffer which didn't quite work, I removed that output buffer, and now nothing gets printed to the screen at all, not even CSS. Could anyone help with this? This is a sample of my code -

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start(PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_CLEANABLE, PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_REMOVABLE);
var_dump($_SESSION['cart']);

$whereIn = implode($_SESSION['cart']);
```

Comment: You still need to call `ob_get_clean()` to output the buffer. Alternative you can store the with `$buffer = ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean()` to echo it later on

Comment: Why are you even output buffering?

Comment: The reason I am output buffering is because for some reason, that var_dump results in the array being outputted to the screen above the content that I want it too, like this - array(15) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(2) "11" [2]=>

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `var_dump`, it should be used for debug purposes

Comment: basically, I have products displayed on a page using a while loop, each containing an 'id' based on the product id, when this button gets pressed, I use an iframe to call a script that adds the ID to an array, that array is then accessed in the basket script, which prints all items in an SQL database where the ID matches the numbers in the array, I was told that using a var_dump is the way to do this? I also use sessions in both scripts.

Comment: also @DarkBee , your method works, the only problem I then get, is that the HTML above that, which looks like this - <html>
    <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>GAMES N' STUFF - Basket</title>
 <link href="gamerch.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>
<div id ="bodybox">
<?php - no longer applies and only outputs the sql items without any css?

Comment: You're storing the id's in the session var `$_SESSION['cart']`? Then the implode should suffice to create your `WHERE IN (?,?,?)` No need to printing out the array if you want to use it somewhere

Comment: yes @DarkBee , thats my point, for some reason the array is being output to screen and I don't know why, if I don't use an output buffer, the array is printed above all contents of my sql database, If I do use one, my css doesn't work?

Comment: actually, I see what you mean, take out the var_dump, and you have fixed it, thank you very much! @DarkBee